# Did yfinance stop providing company name and company logo field when using yf.info method?

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

Trying to retrieve the company full name, company summary description and company logo (logo_url) from yfin...however seemingly not available when using yfin...does yfin only provide ticker information now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you use the following code, it should work:

```
t = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
t.info
```

You should get a dictionnary with the key "shortName" that gives "Microsoft Corporation". Though, there is an open issue on github about a potential throttle on the number of fields that you get after many requests where the company description is lost...

Source of the issue: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1649